# Niddesa Translations

Tags: theravada, pali-canon, pali, translation

I've hunted around a bit online but haven't found much besides some vague "probably not" answers. Has anyone ever come across an English (or other western language) translation of both parts of the Niddesa? I have the Pali Text Society's printings thanks to the Internet Archive, and enough resources to get started learning Pali if I need to, but figured I should try asking here before I attempt that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a [Sinhala translation of the Mahaniddesa](https://suttacentral.net/mnd) and a [Sinhala translation of the Culaniddesa](https://suttacentral.net/cnd) on SuttaCentral. Both were translated by [A. P. de Zoysa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A._P._de_Zoysa).

From there, you can copy and paste the Sinhala texts into [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com), and get it translated into English or another western language of your choice.

For example, I managed to translate the first paragraph of [Mahaniddesa 6 in Sinhala](https://suttacentral.net/mnd6/si/zoysa) to:

> This life is definitely short. ”Life is the existence of life,
> dependence, existence, control, life, sense of life. Again, in two
> respects life is short, a little, life is short because it exists,
> life is short because it is small in nature. How can life be short in
> existence? Lived in the past emotional moment. Not alive. Will not
> live. Does not live in the future psyche. Did not live, did not live.
> Did not live and did not live in the present time mentality. Will not
> live.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! That will probably be faster than learning Pali :)

Comment: Turns out Sutta Central's [data is also publicly available](https://github.com/suttacentral/sc-data/blob/5c060c479f4cb17a0891011d57d4933c81918ead/html_text/si/pli/sutta/kn/mnd/mnd16.html), which means I may be able to automate at least a halfway-readable Google Translate translation all in one go.

Comment: @ZacAnger That's perfect!

Comment: If anyone happens to come across this later, I'm working on doing exactly that over [here](https://github.com/zacanger/niddesa).